# Pass F10 to the application in Gnome-terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I'm running old Debian machine:
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.2 (lenny)
Release:    5.0.2
Codename:   lenny

I open terminal and run Midnight Commander in it. Now I need to quit by pressing F10. But When I do this I'm getting terminal menu:

[image]

How to get MC menu and not terminal one by pressing F10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does F10 in gnome-terminal open the right-click menu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40258/why-does-f10-in-gnome-terminal-open-the-right-click-menu). It seems to be generating *duplicate answers*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to **`Edit->Keyboard`** Shortcuts

And uncheck **"Enable the menu shortcut key"**

to turn it **off**.

Reference link : [here](http://www.trembath.co.za/mctutorial.html).

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 edit->preferences->general (uncheck) enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default)

Comment: Now F10 no longer works in allow application to receive that F10 keystroke value.  Debian 11, Gnome-Terminal 3.30.2

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu 20.04.1, Gnome version 3.36.8 it is:

```
Gnome terminal's "hamburger menu icon"
  > Preferences
    > "General" tab
      > Uncheck the item labeled "Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default)"
```

---

Just a remark: on the same system, a dconf / gsettings setting exists:

`/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/` `shortcuts-enabled`

Its default value is `true`. Currently it does not seem to impact / conflict with the choice made in the terminal preferences UI. Nevertheless I believe it may be useful to remain mindful of its existence... Just in case one day it may start to interfere again ;)

Comment: worked on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, Gnome 42.5 as well

Answer (score 4):

The best way I found in gnome 4 on a Fedora 35 to disable F10 shortcut :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings menu-accelerator-enabled false
```

Hope it helps :)